# Mahapps customize menu

Tags: wpf, styles, mahapps.metro

I would like to modify the built-in menu style provided by MahApps

[image]

I want to remove the border (in white) and to change the selected menu item brush. What is the best way to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

Create a copy of the mahapps menu style [(Can be found there)](https://github.com/robertbaker/Metro/blob/master/MahApps.Metro/Styles/VS/Menu.xaml) in the ressource part of your xaml file (or app.xaml)

Edit the parts you want and use this custom style for your menu

```
<Menu Style="{StaticResource MyCustomMenuStyle}"/>
```